# Bedeutung von "ich erlebe an mir"

Tags: meaning, usage, preposition

Aus [Angela Merkels Rede am 9. November](http://www.bundesregierung.de/Content/DE/Rede/2014/11/2014-11-09-merkel-gedenkstaette-berliner-mauer.html):

> Wir erleben ja alle, wie schnell vergessen wird; auch ich erlebe **an mir**, was mir alles nicht mehr einfällt. Deshalb ist es so wichtig, dass diese Stätten existieren.

Warum wird hier die Präposition **an** benutzt? Ist "ich erlebe an mir" eine gehobene Weise,

> ich erlebe selbst

oder

> ich erlebe persönlich

zu sagen?

Comment: ich vermute mal: sie hat "ich beobachte an mir" und "ich erlebe (selbst)" verwechselt/verbunden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die eigene Entwicklung aus der Betrachterperspektive wahrzunehmen, drückt man völlig legitim mit "an sich (selbst) erleben" aus. Das beschreibt den beobachteten Verlauf der eigenen Veränderung. Es wird damit indirekt auf einen bisher eher unbewusst passierten Vorgang hingewiesen, der einem erst jetzt oder nur gelegentlich bewusst wird. Im Englischen würde man "to experience" verwenden. "An" zeigt, wie man sich symbolisch von außen betrachtet.

"Ich erlebe an ..." gibt neben dem zeitlichen bzw. örtlichen Bezug also auch den Bezugspunkt zu einem Objekt an, worauf sich das Erlebnis bezieht. Weitere Beispiele sind:

```
Ich erlebe an ihm und durch ihn, dass ...
Ich erlebe an einem Menschen meiner Zeit ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Es kann sich um eine Analogiebildung zu *etwas am eigenen Leib erfahren* handeln. Vergleichbar ist auch *ich sehe das an mir (selbst)*. Man kann auch *ganz neue Seiten an sich / an jemandem kennenlernen*. Umgangssprachlich sagt man dann: *So kannte ich mich/ihn/sie noch gar nicht.*